# Making a maximally mixed 2-qubit state in the IBM Q

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, gate-synthesis, ibm-q-experience

I am trying to make a 2-qubit maximally mixed state $\mathbb{I}/4$ where $\mathbb{I}$ is the identity $4\times 4$ matrix.

I know that, for a maximally mixed 1-qubit state I can use a Hadamard gate, and a CNOT gate with an ancilla, and then trace out the ancilla as follows:

$$(H\otimes \mathrm{id})(|0\rangle \otimes |0\rangle)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)$$

Therefore, the density matrix would be

$$\rho=\frac{1}{2}(|0\rangle\langle0| + |1\rangle\langle1|)=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

How can I do the same for 2 qubits?

Answer (score 2):

Prepare two qubits each in the single-qubit maximally mixed state.  Their state together will be the two-qubit maximally mixed state ;)  You could prepare them sequentially and use the same ancillary qubit for both.

Comment: I tried doing it with the same ancillary qubit for both, but it seems that this is only possible in the simulator. I wanted to run it in the real processor if possible, but I managed to do it in the simulator the way you told me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Huh.  Can you do it on the real processor using two ancillary qubits, one for each target qubit?  I don't know much about the IBM-Q machine, but it seems like this at least should be possible.